# Please tell people to put meta-related questions into meta

Tags: discussion

[Unable to logout from Ask Ubuntu Forum](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15855/unable-to-logout-from-ask-ubuntu-forum)

An example ^.

Can people tell them to put meta-related stuff to Meta instead? It's a waste of time and daily vote limit.

...Right?

Comment: It rarely happens though, so it is not a big deal even if you have a small number of flags.

Comment: even humble users can select 'belongs on AU meta' in the flagging dialog... I'd rather use a flag (and these days I get more flags than I ever manage to use up) than have a tedious comment conversation with a confused user

Comment: People who confuse the main Ask Ubuntu site with Ask Ubuntu Meta are our smallest problem on the site. It only happens extremely rarely. There are dozens or hundreds of questions to be closed as off-topic because they're about other systems, programming etc., we even get magnitudes more spam than those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already tell them this on the page you write questions:

[image]

We also have fairly extensive documentation about what is on-topic on the main site.

When else would you like us to tell people this stuff. Short of actually physically talking to every new user before they post something, we've done about as much as we can. Just flag to close and migrate to Meta (when you can).

Comment: @olli Thank you.